# Could not get record of current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to fetch data from database based on current date,In mysql it working perfect using `NOW()` but i have tried using following way for php but it's not work (It's display old date data also).

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "SELECT  a.created_date,a.shipment_id,o.order_id, o.customer_id,c.delivery_method
        FROM  `orders` AS o
        INNER JOIN  `table_1` AS a ON o.order_id = a.order_id
        INNER JOIN  `table_2` as c ON c.id=o.customer_id
        WHERE a.manifest_create_status =0 
            AND a.active_status=1 
            AND o.customer_id IN ($id)
            AND a.created_date > $date 
        ORDER BY a.created_date";
```

Is anything wrong in query ?

Comment: `a.created_date` has only date or timestamp?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, and also at risk of unexpected syntax errors. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quotes around the date value, like `a.created_date > '$date'`.

Also please note that expression `o.customer_id IN ($id)` would be better written `o.customer_id = $id`.

Query :

```
$sql = "SELECT  a.created_date,a.shipment_id,o.order_id, o.customer_id,c.delivery_method
        FROM  `orders` AS o
        INNER JOIN  `table_1` AS a ON o.order_id = a.order_id
        INNER JOIN  `table_2` as c ON c.id=o.customer_id
        WHERE a.manifest_create_status =0 
            AND a.active_status=1 
            AND o.customer_id = $id
            AND a.created_date > '$date' 
        ORDER BY a.created_date";
```

To avoid this type of issue, while also providing protection against any type of bind injection (where does the `id` comes from ?), I would recommend to use bind parameters, as follows :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT  a.created_date,a.shipment_id,o.order_id, o.customer_id,c.delivery_method
        FROM  `orders` AS o
        INNER JOIN  `table_1` AS a ON o.order_id = a.order_id
        INNER JOIN  `table_2` as c ON c.id=o.customer_id
        WHERE a.manifest_create_status =0 
            AND a.active_status=1 
            AND o.customer_id = ?
            AND a.created_date > ? 
        ORDER BY a.created_date";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $date);
$stmt->execute();
```